# Identification of shrub with variegated leaves and white flowers

Tags: identification, flowers, shrubs

A friend of mine has seen this plant in a cemetery in Romania, zone 6b, and wants to know its name.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Euphorbia marginata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_marginata) from the same family as Poinsettia, possibly the variety 'Kilimanjaro' as Bamboo says. It is a weird white one with variegated leaves and bracts, as can be seen [in this photo](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/118641771407856022/?lp=true).

Comment: Euphorbia marginata, possibly the variety 'Kilimanjaro' to be exact - self seeding annual, occasionally perennial

Comment: Shoot, Bamboo...do that in an answer.  Poinsettia is a Euphorbia and marginata  var. Kilimanjaro is perfect.  My answer wasn't very specific.  Grins!

Comment: No, why don't you just tart up your own answer with the extra info...you got it first, you just didn't do a proper answer. It's a lovely looking plant though..

Comment: hey, looked it up and well, lets take this to chat!  Our own room.  Got some out there information not pertinent to this question...grins.

Comment: Thank you, stormy! In the link you provided there was the current name of Euphorbia marginata and that's why I upvoted your answer immediatly. I have now edited your answer so I could accept it, hope you don't mind. My friend was impressed for such a quick ID.